# In a widget factory, machine $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively produce $35\%$, $25\%$, and $40\%$ of the total output.

Tags: probability, statistics

In a widget factory, machine $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively produce $35\%$, $25\%$, and $40\%$ of the total output.  Of the respective outputs, $7\%$, $5\%$, and $2\%$ are defective.  A widget is selected at random.

a)  What is the probably that it is defective?

$P(M_1)=.35$, $P(M_2)=.25$, $P(M_3)=.40$

$P(D \mid M_1)=.07$, $P(D \mid M_2)=.05$, $P(D \mid M_3) =.02$

$P(D)= P(D \mid M_1)P(M_1)+P(D \mid M_2)P(M_2)+ P(D \mid M_3)P(M_3)$

$P(D)=0.045$

b)  Given that it is defective, what is the probably that it was produced by machine 1?

$P(M_1 \mid D)= \dfrac{P(M_1 \cap D)}{P(D)} = 0.544$

Could you please check it for me?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

Your solutions are correct.